# gio.h no such file or directory

Tags: linux, gio

I am trying to compile the GIO example program code at here on [developer.gnome.org](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GDBusServer.html) link. And the command I am using to compile it is

```
    g++ gdbserver.cpp `pkg-config glib-2.0 --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 gio-unix-2.0`
```

But an error message

```
    package gio-unix-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path
    (... the remaining pkg-config message ...)
    error: gio/gio.h: No such file or directory
    (... other g++ error messages ...)
```

glib and glib-devel are installed ( I think GIO comes with glib, right?)
Is there a mistake I am doing here.

edit : The centos5.5 I am using (I am supposed to use it) has glib2 version 2.12 and only glib2 with version 2.15 or higher come along with GIO. I am not sure how to install GIO seperately.

Comment: try running "find /usr/include -name gio" and see if you can find the gio folder(I have the following result:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio
/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/gio
).

Comment: @izomorphius not present! I should install it then, I guess. But then I could not find any library, which could have GIO, after searching yum.

Comment: Hmm that is strange. I really think gio is part of glib-2.0. Maybe try reinstalling that?

Comment: @izomorphius I just realized that the glib version is 1.2.10 (output of glib-config --version).

Comment: @izomorphius Does GIO not come with the older versions of glib?)

Comment: @izomorphius I am sorry for the continuous updates but pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 does return the appropriate paths. so glib-2.0 is installed. I have reinstalled it as you have asked, but with out any success.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
g++ gdbserver.cpp `pkg-config glib-2.0 gio-2.0 --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 gio-unix-2.0`
```

(Note the addition of the `gio-2.0` pkg-config name.)

Answer (score -1):

CentOS 5.5 does not have gio. It uses gvfs instead.

Comment: I see. Is it not even possible to install GIO?

Comment: Not separately from glib, no.